# Reading Data from a File in Python with Exceptions

Tags: python

I have to write a program that will read data from a file, convert it to an integer and total the amount. So far here is what i have. The numbers from the data file "numdata.txt" are: 78,93,85,100,81,76,94,77.

```
def main():
total = 0

try:
    NumberFile = open('numdata.txt', 'r')

    for line in NumberFile:
        amount = float(line)
        total += amount
        print(format(total, ',.2f'))

except IOError:
    print('An error occurred trying to read the file.')

except ValueError:
    print('Non-numeric data found in the file.')

except:
    print('An error has occurred.')

finally:
     NumberFile.close()


main()
```

When i run the program the first number (78) gets displayed and then one of the exception error messages comes up, the weird thing is that it's different sometimes. If someone could help point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. I'm still very new to this so please bear with me.

I tried and tried but could not get the loop to work correctly so i ended up going this route:

```
def main ():
infile = open('numdata.txt', 'r')
num1 = int(infile.readline())
num2 = int(infile.readline())
num3 = int(infile.readline())
num4 = int(infile.readline())
num5 = int(infile.readline())
num6 = int(infile.readline())
num7 = int(infile.readline())
num8 = int(infile.readline())
infile.close()
total = num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8
average = total/8
print('the total: ', total)
print('the average: ', average)
```

main()

It's not pretty but it works i guess lol

Comment: Can you please reformat your code?

Comment: sorry i didnt see your comment, i think i did what you asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = 0    

try:
    NumberFile = open('numdata.txt', 'r')

    for line in NumberFile:
        amount = float(line)
        total += amount
        print(format(total, ',.2f'))
except IOError:
    print('An error occurred trying to read the file.')
except ValueError:
    print('Non-numeric data found in the file.')
except:
    print('An error has occurred.')
finally:
    NumberFile.close()
```

The exception occurs because you're closing the file immediately after the first iteration, leaving you unable to iterate over the rest of it.

Moving `NumberFile.close()` to a finally clause ensures the file is closed no matter what goes wrong.  However, a much better way to read / write files in Python is to use the [`with` keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), which is a built-in method of ensuring the same thing.

```
total = 0

with open('numdata.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            total += float(line)
        except ValueError:
            print('Non-numeric data found in the file.')
            continue
        finally:
            print('{:.2f}'.format(total, ',.2f'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it. I'm stiill having a small issue, once the numbers are all totaled I get the value error message appearing at the end, any way to get that to not show up? Again thanks for the help :)

Comment: What sort of values do you have in your file?  I suspect you'd be better off moving the ```try: / except ValueError:``` inside the the for loop.  If there's an exception, maybe print out the value so you know what cause the problem, then ```continue``` onto the next iteration.

Comment: the file is just a regular notepad file. i'll try moving the exception error and see if i can get it to work. i was also thinking maybe of having it total the sum, find an average and display it as a percentage. Would i just need to add in some coding for finding the average and then converting it to percentage? or would the format function take care of the percentage part?

Comment: Format just looks after the formatting of a given variable.  Use ```{:.2%}``` to display a value with a percentage symbol.  Check out the statistics module if you're looking for an easy way to find average values: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html  Please mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it.  :)

Comment: just marked it. thanks again for all the help, take care - dan

Comment: Hi again, I tried to see if i could get this to do what i want but cant seem to figure it out. I still get a value error message at the bottom after the numbers have all been added. Also i cant get the total to print using a regular old print function. Would it be possible for you to copy and paste my code into python on your end to see whats going on? I'm new to all of this and you've been very helpful, thanks

Comment: I've added a print statement to ensure the total is printed on each iteration regardless of whether an error occurred.  If you don't want to see the error message just remove the ```print('Non-numeric data found in the file.')``` line.  The program will still continue, but won't warn you when there's an error.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help but unfortunately its still not doing what i need it to do and i dont know enough about programming to make it work. i've tried about a dozen tutorials and none of those work, video lessons arent working, it just doesnt make sense. i copy everything word for word and the examples work for the person doing them just not me. so frustrating.

Comment: heres the lesson im trying to do: "Create a program that reads all of the numbers stored in a file and calculates the total (sum) then displays the value as total points to screen.  Next, have the program calculate the average score then display the value as percent score to screen.  Next, make sure the program handles IOError and ValueError exceptions. I know this is a basic program but i just cannot get it to work, thanks again for helping

Answer (score 0):

you are closing the file in first iteration `NumberFile.close()` is not indented properly